# What kind of changes do I need to this so I can auto sort two columns in Google sheets (date columns)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two columns - column 4 is a date, column 5 is a time field (HH:MM). I would like it to auto sort by both (ascending).

The code below works if both columns are numbers but doesn't work when I do data validation and convert column 4 into a date field and 5 into time (HH:MM).

I'm not adamant on using a modification of the script below, couldn't think of a clean formula that would get the job done (using one sheet).

```
var SORT_COLUMN_INDEX = 4;
var SORT_COLUMN_SECOND = 5;
var ASCENDING = true;
var NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS = 1;
var activeSheet;
function autoSort(sheet) {
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  if (NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS > 0) {
    range = range.offset(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS, 0);
  }

  // Perform the actual sort.
  range.sort( {
    column: SORT_COLUMN_SECOND,
    ascending: ASCENDING
  });
  range.sort( {
    column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX,
    ascending: ASCENDING
  } );
}
function onEdit(event) {
  var editedCell;
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  editedCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
  if (editedCell.getColumn() == SORT_COLUMN_INDEX) {
    autoSort(activeSheet);
  }
}
function onOpen(event) {
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  autoSort(activeSheet);
}
function onInstall(event) {
  onOpen(event);
}
```

Comment: I would consider combining the two columns in to a date time column.

Answer (score 1):

This function combines COL3 and COL4 using the column 3 as the day and  column 4 as the hour and replaces column 3 with a datetime.  It also deletes column 4 and writes the  data back into the spreadsheet and sorts on column 3 which is now a datetime.

```
function myfunc() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const [hA, ...rows]=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let idx={};
  hA.forEach((h,i)=>{idx[h]=i;});
  let vA=rows.map((r,i)=>{
    r[idx['COL3']]= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2021,0,r[idx['COL3']-1],r[idx['COL4']]),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    return [r[idx['COL1']],r[idx['COL2']],r[idx['COL3']],r[idx['COL5']],r[idx['COL6']],r[idx['COL7']],r[idx['COL8']],r[idx['COL9']],r[idx['COL10']]];
  });
  hA.splice(3,1);
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,1,hA.length).setValues([hA]);
  sh.getRange(2,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
  sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastRow()).sort({column:3,ascending:true});;
}
```

Starting Data with random numbers:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 14 | 18 | 9 | 5 | 16 | 18 | 13 | 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 | 12 | 6 | 4 | 10 | 15 | 14 | 15 | 11 |
| 0 | 9 | 3 | 12 | 9 | 14 | 17 | 6 | 8 | 5 |
| 16 | 15 | 17 | 17 | 12 | 9 | 14 | 15 | 5 | 16 |
| 3 | 6 | 15 | 6 | 0 | 9 | 15 | 8 | 0 | 8 |
| 13 | 8 | 13 | 8 | 15 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 16 | 13 |
| 2 | 10 | 11 | 3 | 14 | 14 | 1 | 19 | 5 | 1 |
| 12 | 5 | 3 | 14 | 5 | 2 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 3 |
| 12 | 4 | 6 | 9 | 8 | 15 | 15 | 16 | 4 | 18 |
| 3 | 18 | 15 | 15 | 7 | 3 | 15 | 18 | 5 | 2 |
| 11 | 5 | 3 | 6 | 13 | 15 | 15 | 18 | 9 | 14 |
| 2 | 10 | 4 | 4 | 8 | 16 | 13 | 8 | 0 | 11 |
| 0 | 7 | 3 | 10 | 9 | 2 | 6 | 11 | 11 | 11 |
| 17 | 9 | 17 | 10 | 11 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 12 | 19 |
| 11 | 8 | 19 | 10 | 7 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 1 | 6 |
| 8 | 3 | 7 | 4 | 17 | 3 | 11 | 1 | 19 | 13 |
| 9 | 17 | 16 | 15 | 17 | 4 | 16 | 13 | 15 | 10 |
| 7 | 13 | 1 | 15 | 8 | 17 | 6 | 4 | 6 | 12 |
| 11 | 10 | 5 | 19 | 10 | 6 | 8 | 12 | 17 | 12 |
| 16 | 18 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 11 | 3 | 19 | 2 | 8 |

And then after running the function:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 3 | Sun Jan 03 2021 04:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 17 | 3 | 11 | 1 | 19 | 13 |
| 12 | 4 | Mon Jan 04 2021 09:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 8 | 15 | 15 | 16 | 4 | 18 |
| 11 | 5 | Tue Jan 05 2021 06:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 13 | 15 | 15 | 18 | 9 | 14 |
| 12 | 5 | Tue Jan 05 2021 14:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 5 | 2 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 | Wed Jan 06 2021 06:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 4 | 10 | 15 | 14 | 15 | 11 |
| 3 | 6 | Wed Jan 06 2021 06:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 0 | 9 | 15 | 8 | 0 | 8 |
| 0 | 7 | Thu Jan 07 2021 10:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 9 | 2 | 6 | 11 | 11 | 11 |
| 13 | 8 | Fri Jan 08 2021 08:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 15 | 0 | 4 | 1 | 16 | 13 |
| 11 | 8 | Fri Jan 08 2021 10:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 7 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 1 | 6 |
| 17 | 9 | Sat Jan 09 2021 10:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 11 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 12 | 19 |
| 0 | 9 | Sat Jan 09 2021 12:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 9 | 14 | 17 | 6 | 8 | 5 |
| 2 | 10 | Sun Jan 10 2021 03:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 14 | 14 | 1 | 19 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 | Sun Jan 10 2021 04:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 8 | 16 | 13 | 8 | 0 | 11 |
| 11 | 10 | Sun Jan 10 2021 19:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 10 | 6 | 8 | 12 | 17 | 12 |
| 7 | 13 | Wed Jan 13 2021 15:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 8 | 17 | 6 | 4 | 6 | 12 |
| 8 | 14 | Thu Jan 14 2021 09:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 5 | 16 | 18 | 13 | 4 | 3 |
| 16 | 15 | Fri Jan 15 2021 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 12 | 9 | 14 | 15 | 5 | 16 |
| 9 | 17 | Sun Jan 17 2021 15:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 17 | 4 | 16 | 13 | 15 | 10 |
| 16 | 18 | Mon Jan 18 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 4 | 11 | 3 | 19 | 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 18 | Mon Jan 18 2021 15:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) | 7 | 3 | 15 | 18 | 5 | 2 |